# Automatically sorta table in a CakePHP web app

Tags: php, html, cakephp, paginator

I have a table displayed in a page within my CakePHP web app set with paginator.
The table always appears sorted ascending on *'id'* (I really don't know why) and I would like it to be sorted also on *'id'* but descending.
Do you know if there is any simple function to make this thing happen?
Please, find the code below.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('contact_id') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('sum_price') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>            
            <tr>
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($order->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= $this->Html->link($order->Contacts["name"] , ['controller' => 'Contacts', 'action' => 'view', $order->Contacts["id"]]) : '' ?></td>              
                <td><?= $this->Number->format($order->sum_price) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So far paginator is working fine, so I can click on the column headers to sort the data. Anyway, I would like it to be displayed properly as it loads for the first time.

Please, let me know if there is any other piece of code that might be important.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

In case it helps, I have these two functions in my app controller:

```
public function all()
    {
        $orders = $this->Orders->find("all")->contain(["contacts"]);
        $orders = $this->paginate($orders);
        $this->set(compact('orders'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("admin");
    }

public function view($id = null)
    {
        $this->loadModel('ContactAdresses');
        $this->loadModel('Contacts');
        $order = $this->Orders->get($id, ['contain' => ['Contacts']]);
        $contactId = $order->contact->id;
        $contact = $this->Contacts->get($contactId, ['contain' => ['ContactAdresses']]);
        $this->set('order', $order);
        $this->set('contact_adress', $contact->contact_adress);
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("admin");
    }
```

Comment: It would be interesting to share your controller. You can change this using, for example: -> order (['id' => 'DESC']); See the example in the documentation: 

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: @EdrianBiagi I don't really understand your syntax. I understand you suggest to modify this line: `<td><?= $this->Number->format($order->id) ?></td>` How would be the exact change?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function all()
    {
        $orders = $this->Orders->find("all", ['order' => ['id' => 'DESC']])->contain(["contacts"]);
        $orders = $this->paginate($orders);
        $this->set(compact('orders'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("admin");
    }
```

OR

```
     public function all()
     {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['contacts',],
            'order'   => ['id' => 'DESC'],
            ],
        ];
        
        $query = $this->Orders->find('all');
        $this->set('orders', $this->paginate($query));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("admin");
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @EdrianBiagi but none of your two options work. I get an error when going to the orders page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a functional code snippet that I wrote.

```
public function index() {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Ctrs', 'States', 'Stages'],
            'order' => ['created' => 'DESC']            
        ];
        $movements = $this->paginate($this->Movements);

        $this->set(compact('movements'));
    }
```